# Calling a function when in background doesnt work (React-Native, AppState)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state, background-process

I am using AppState to check when app goes to background so that I can call a function same as it is called when in Foreground.

**Function which is called after state changed:**

```
    _handleAppStateChange = () => {
    if (AppState.currentState === 'background') {
        console.log('App has come to the background!')
        this._getDataHandler();
    }
    //this.setState({ appState: nextAppState });
}
```

**The other function which is called inside the previous one:**

```
_getDataHandler(){
console.log('_getDataHandler is called');

    clearInterval(this.carInterval);
        this.carInterval = setInterval(() => {
            try {
                //some functions
            } catch (Exception) {
                console.log("Error: " + Exception);
            }
        }, 5000);}
```

**componentDidMount() :**

```
    componentDidMount() {
        AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
}
```

**componentWillUnmount():**

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
}
```

**Now, the porblem is that `_getDataHandler` is being called but its not implementing the functionality which is inside, only printing the first line.**

Comment:  That code is in need of some serious refactoring. It's nigh-impossible to have any idea what it's doing. I suggest you separate the increasingly deep parts into separate functions, and at the very least pare it down to an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us. I think you also need to read this guide on promise antipatterns: http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/ I bet that, despite all of the `catch`es there (you should have far, far fewer of them), there is an unhandled error being thrown somewhere.

Comment: @JLRishe thanks for the suggestion but thats not what i asked

Comment: @JLRishe check the updated code. Much simpler!

Comment: Thank you. Always important here on SO to distill a problem down to its most essential parts. Have you tried placing a `console.log` right inside the `setinterval` callback to see if the callback is running? I haven't done much mobile development, but my understanding is that mobile devices can highly limit what apps are able to do while they're in the background, so that may be why your code isn't running. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable about that can weigh in on the matter, but AFAIK Apple devices (almost?) completely lock down background apps and it's a configurable setting on Android

Comment: First create interval then clear interval

Comment: @NijatAliyev can AppState be actually used to run a task on the background? Or is it just for letting me know when the state changes?!

Comment: @JLRishe can AppState be actually used to run a task on the background? Or is it just for letting me know when the state changes?!

Comment: @bmm I haven't used AppState, but according to its [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate), it looks like its purpose is for checking the current state and notifying of state changes. I suspect it doesn't provide some special ability to run background code: "AppState can tell you if the app is in the foreground or background, and notify you when the state changes.

AppState is frequently used to determine the intent and proper behavior when handling push notifications."